# TypeScript @types version related to Library version

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can anyone explain the versioning behind TypeScript @types
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

For example:
I assumed that if I was using mocha@3.4.2 then I would been to install @types/mocha@3.4.2.

Howerver, this version does not exist. It get worse. for example, react-addons-test-utils@15.6.0 and @types/react-addons-test-utils@0.14.19. What does that mean? What version is this targeting?

How, can I make sure that I'm installing the correct version of the Types for the library version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortionaly it may be just a "doing it wrong" matter. Generally, It's a good practice to give the `@types` version the same version of the library itself. But regarding the patch part of the semantic version, it will differ in most cases.

**Possible causes why versions may differ:**

1. There are no updates in types so the library has been patched for example but the `@types` one hasn't.
2. `@types` library is not well maintained.
3. `@types` library has many bugs and patches.

**Nice to mention:**

You can definitely contribute to any `@types` library and help to keep it well versioned.

Comment: Thanx, I thought that I was missing the big picture somewhere. I have noticed that the version number is included as a comment in most \@Types. It's making me mad that some packages are updated to the latest version of TypeScript for no real reason. This stops me from being able to use some of the latest \@Types as I am locked-in to an older version of TypeScript. Thanx for the info

Comment: Welcome.. Glad to help :)