# Package.json how to match @types for libraries

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, types, package.json

What is the best way to match types for the library?

I tried to put the same versions for libs as for the @types but it is not working all the time

Not the best example(This is just an example please ignore the message that this is deprecated):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch <- 3.0.0

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/whatwg-fetch <- 0.0.33

I have such a situation with a lot of libs at work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript @types version related to Library version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848828/typescript-types-version-related-to-library-version)